# Xdebug hiding dump information?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, dump

I am using xdebug with my php methods such as var_dump() are beautiful but not showing full information instead the dump ends with three dots `...` which might be the sign of continuation followed by

```
(length=87749)
```

How should I tell xdebug to show full dump ??
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xdebug truncates the output of *(at least)* strings and arrays, to avoid it getting to big.

The amout of data that's printed can be configured using these directives :

- [`xdebug.var_display_max_children`](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_children)
- [`xdebug.var_display_max_data`](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_data)
- and [`xdebug.var_display_max_depth`](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_depth)

For more informations and example, see [**Variable Display Features**](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/display)

You'll have to edit your `php.ini` file *(or `xdebug.ini` file, depending on your setup)*, to define those directives, with values that suit your needs.

For example, on Ubuntu, in my `/etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini` file, I have the following lines :

```
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 2048
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 8
```

Comment: thanks for links found "xdebug.var_display_max_data" solved the problem

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this w/o access to the php.ini?

Answer (score 2):

Just edit in your php.ini file

```
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 10 #example
```

Answer (score 0):

@Smittles - xdebug vars can be set at runtime via ini_set:

```
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 5);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', 256);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 1024);
```

See Michael Berkowski's excellent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9998628/6073709