# Only last element of array is displayed

Tags: php, foreach

Example: When adding square brackets to $main_array, I get 3 dots inside array but when I remove those brackets, it works good.

```
    <?php
$user = array('a','b','c');
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
$roll = array(1,2,3);

$length = count($user);

$main_array = array();

foreach($user as $name){
    $list = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        $list[] = array(
            'label' => $cars[$i],
            'roll' => $roll[$i] 
        );
    }

    $main_array[] = array(
        'name'=> $name,
        'list'=> $list
    );

}
var_dump($main_array);
?>
```

Added....
So here is what I am trying to do. Trying to pull feed from twitter api 1.1

```
$status = array();
$tweetfeed = array();
foreach($users as $user){
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$user."&count=".$notweets);
    $t=0;
    foreach($tweets as $key) {  
        $status[$t]['text'] = $key ->text;
        $status[$t]['stamp'] = twitter_time($key -> created_at);
        ++$t;
    }   
    $tweetfeed = array (
        'status' => $status         
    );  
var_dump($tweetfeed);
}
var_dump($tweetfeed);
```

..End

```
   foreach($user)
    Main_parent {
         Child-1{
                 'key': value
                 'key': value
         }

         Child-2{
                 'key': value
                 'key': value
         }
         Child-3{
                 'key': value
                 'key': value
         }

    }
var_dump(Main_parent);
    }
var_dump(Main_parent);
```

Calling Main_parent with in foreach loop is working fine but when called outside foreach loop is only showing child-3.

Comment: What langage is this supposed to be? looks like a mix of php and javascript.

Comment: That's because you retain only the last value.

Comment: @user574632... I am writing this in PHP

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: @machineaddict so how can I correct this to get entire array after the foreach loop. Thanks

Comment: Sure, but the code in your question is not php

Comment: code updated. Can you please check... I tried to generalise when I asked initially but it literally flopped

Comment: Ok, now it maks sense! Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `$tweetfeed` in every itteration.

```
 $tweetfeed = array (
        'status' => $status         
    );
```

Should be:

```
 $tweetfeed[] = array (
        'status' => $status         
    );
```

By using `[]` you are pushing the value into the array, rather than overwriting it. You could actually simplify the whole thing to:

```
$tweetfeed = array();
foreach($users as $user){
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$user."&count=".$notweets);
    $status = array();
    foreach($tweets as $key) {  
        $status[]=array(
                        'text' => $key ->text, 
                        'stamp' => twitter_time($key -> created_at)
                       );
    }   
    $tweetfeed[] = array (
        'status' => $status         
    );  
var_dump($tweetfeed);
}
var_dump($tweetfeed);
```

Comment: As said, If I add square bracket to tweetfeed, I am getting the array structure out as expected but within the status array, there is no content, only 3 dots... If I remove the square brackets, only last element of tweetfeed is shown but the status array has the content in it.

Comment: @pmvsdt What do you mean three dots?? Whether you push the data into an array, or overwrite a variable, it wont change the data in $status. Can you make a live example, for example here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ so i can see what you mean

Comment: Edited my question and added example. Please check. Thanks

Comment: @pmvsdt Still not seeing a problem, your example works just fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/iuLycB#

Comment: For some reason, I dont get any data in the main_array with squarebrackets. Tried different browsers with cache cleared. Can you please copy that code to php file and view it in browser. Thanks

Comment: @pmvsdt I really dont understand what you mean, the codepad link should show you there is no problem, but here is a screengrab from chrome, running the exact code from your example on a local server: http://i.imgur.com/uf33mjm.png

Comment: and here is a screenshot of what i am getting... unable to understand how to resole this... tried in different system too http://imgur.com/TIFPCjR

Comment: @pmvsdt Thats just your browser truncating the data. Maybe its a plugin, but the important thing is its just the display, the code and data is fine. If you want to see the raw data without your browser interfering, just right click and select view source

Comment: If I remove square brackets to main_array, then the entire is displaying properly within foreach loop. But outside foreach, only the last element of main_array is displayed

Comment: @pmvsdt Why are we going round in circles here? This has nothing to do with the code. Its just your browser. Did you try 'view page source'

Comment: @pmvsdt Or are you using xdebug? That also truncates data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127842/xdebug-hiding-dump-information But either way, its just how the data is displayed to you, the actual data is fine

Comment: Here is a screenshot of pagesource http://imgur.com/LAq5Skv

Comment: Alright, atlast, found a solution.. The problem is with localhost. I pushed the file to production and it worked.. But is there any reason why this code will not work on localhost..

Comment: Yup, it's x debug on localhost. See the link above